# Android app to to block international calls from a particular country

Tags: android

I am being plagued by a call back scam, where I get calls from numbers beginning +224 (Guinea), +252 (Somalia) and a few other countries. The call rings once and disconnects, and I suppose I am expected to call them at exorbitant call rates, from which they get a cut (just like calling domestic premium numbers).

[This question](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-way-to-block-international-calls-from-a-particular-country-using-just-the-country-code-and-not-the-full-phone-number-on-an-Android-phone) tells me how to do it using Android settings, but I can't find the setting on my phone. I asked friends to check, in case I had overlooked it, but they can't find it either.

Is there a free Android app to do so? (I'm looking at you @Izzzy ;-)

Comment: As you ask me directly, you surely wanted my [Call Blocker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various#group_97) app list? I'm not using any myself, so I cannot give a direct recommendation (only the hint to "beware": some of the better knowns have privacy issues, eg. TrueCaller and Sync.Me I'd rather avoid).

Comment: Urk! I am already using TrueCaller. I accept that I had to tell them who I Am - any other problems?

Comment: Just check the links in my list, I don't remember the details exactly. Something with collecting your data etc. AFAIR. [This English warning](http://www.ethow.com/2015/10/how-Truecaller-works-is-what-you-might-not-like.html) is two years old, but describing "how it works" should be still valid. Quote: "it simply uploads each and every contact and information linked to it from your phone’s contact list to its servers" (data used ao. for caller info). The article concludes: "it is just privacy risk for almost all users". Read for yourself.

Comment: Damage done - too late now :-(  Or is it? I will take a look at your list, maybe even ask here for an alternative

Comment: The article writes about the ability to remove a number. But that could be a hard job with your entire list, and I don't know if there's a guarantee the data will really be deleted from their servers (they could always claim they don't know who else provided it as well, and insist to only remove details on *your own* record – i.e. your phone number).

Comment: Coincidence? See what just popped up an hour ago at Android.SE: [Does TrueCalller App leak your phonebook?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/184848/16575) And check my comment on the answer ;)

Comment: Of course, we should have realized that, without having to read the small print. I could code my own, but am too busy/lazy. Fortunately, the only people in my address book are recruitment agents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking the emphasis on privacy, the most obvious source to look at is [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org). So checking my [Call Blocker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various#group_97) app list with that in mind (simply watch out for F-Droid icons next to the app names), **[NoPhoneSpam](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=at.bitfire.nophonespam)** sounds like a good candidate – and meets your requirements (as I understand them):

- **can block calls:** sure :)
- **can block by country code:** Yes (quote: "Use special syntax to block countries or providers or parts of numbers")
- **respects your privacy:** Yes. Minimal permissions (read phone state, calls) – only those really needed. No network permissions.

Just in case, it's also [available at Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.bitfire.nophonespam) – though I definitely recommend using F-Droid wherever possible (for privacy reasons).

Note, however, that this app hasn't been updated for about a year – which mustn't mean much, of course, as long as it works :)

Comment: There were some good answers from Alex, prettier with more features, but if FOSS can get the job done, then it's always my choice. I have installed No Phone Spam and am waiting to test it.

Comment: And do not use TrueCaller because of its privacy leak with your phonebook: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/184860/9897

Comment: Is there any native support coming for phone blocker in Oreo? I cannot trust 3rd party apps with such a basic function.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 No idea. I don't even run Nougat yet, as XPrivacy no longer supports it (and the Xposed framework wasn't available for it until recently). So I have to delegate that question – which btw is better fitting for Android.SE as it's not asking for a "software recommendation" but a potential feature of some Android version ;)

Comment: @Izzy I extended the feature need discussion here https://android.stackexchange.com/q/184862/9897

Answer (score 2):

I've seen two apps that seem to be doing what you want:

1. [Call Blocker Free - Blacklist](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netqin.mm&hl=en):

   - is free,
   - but contains ads,
   - allows you to block one ring phone scams,
2. [Calls Blacklist - Call Blocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vladlee.easyblacklist&hl=en):

   - is free,
   - contains ads,
   - offers in-app purchases,
   - allows you to block numbers starting with, say, a country code.

Btw, I checked and I couldn't find the settings to block callers on my Android phone either. No idea what is up with that.

Comment: I have installed both and will trial them for a day to decide which one I should use. Good tips, thanks

Comment: First impression, after a few minutes only - NQ Call Blocker Free is ***very*** slow, and I can't see its "DETECT AND STOP ONE-RING PHONE SCAM" feature. Calls Blacklist was responsive and intuitive and I easily found the "number begins with ..." option. As soon as it successfully blocks its first call, I will award the anser

Comment: From the features listed, I wonder what for "Calls Blacklist" requires access to accounts (incl. authenticate_accounts), Internet, GCM?